# Detecting entering Street View after user clicks in Google Maps info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to be able to detect when a user clicks in a Google Maps info window to enter Street View. This can happen after the user clicks a marker on a map such as one for a restaurant or whatever. They click on the marker on the map and then an info window comes up in which they can click to enter Street View.

Also, does that open Street View in a new object on top of the map or does it open the Street View within the map object? How is one supposed to handle this non-standard entry into Street View? I note that the user can get back to the map by clicking a right arrow at top left of the street view. I also note that after the user enters Street View this way, that the panorama.getVisible() property is false.

Comment: Do you have some example available? from the description it's not clear what you want to achieve. Does clicking on infoWindow to enter StreetView already work for you or you need help with this part? Or you already have that only want some improvements? Share the parts of code if you want us to be able to help you

Comment: Here is an example. My app is http://globebop.com/web . Click the Map View button to the right of the globe. This button takes you back and forth between Street View and Map View. Notice that when you click that button repeatedly it works fine. Now go to Map View. You should see on the map some round Google Map markers which, when clicked, show a graphic that says "Street View". Click such a graphic to enter Street View. This is the event I need to be able to detect. Cuz now, when you click the Map View/Street View button, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the 'visible_changed' event? Here is a sample that works for me using the getVisible().

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Catch panorama change</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
      #map {height: 100%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var panorama;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 49.288, lng: -123.11},
          zoom: 17
        });
        panorama = map.getStreetView();
        panorama.addListener('visible_changed', function() {
            if (panorama.getVisible()) {
                console.log('Entering streetview');
            } else {
                console.log('Leaving streetview');
            }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe your project is more complex and needs more adjustment. But otherwise in the new API (ver > 3.22) the infowindow does not include the streetview.